# Detect the nearest divs to the center screen when scrolling jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect which div is nearest to the screen center, while scrolling horizontally. Once detected, I want to do something such as trigger an event.

[image]

```
var screenW = ($(window).width() /2);

$('div.fistSlider').bind('mousemove', function(e){
    var xN = e.pageX + 16;
    $('div#divContainer').scrollLeft(xN);
});
```

When the div nearest to red line (the center of screen), should do some event.

Comment: I cleaned up this question by inlining your image and rephrasing it somewhat. But can you post what you have already tried so that people can remark on it? In general, a question that doesn't show what you've tried already won't gather many positive responses.

Comment: Do you mean the center of the screen or the center of the containing element? That greatly changes possible solutions. Calculating center of the screen is harder. Also are you assuming all divs are tiled horizontally? or do you want all divs that have the highest number of pixels crossing the center line? What if no div crosses the center line? This needs way more detail. The easiest thing to do here would be to TDD it and show us the tests you would like it to pass.

Comment: sorry for that, i edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to check for the offset of each div.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('div').each(function(){
        var centerLine = $(window).width()/2;
        var divStart = $(this).offset().left;
        var divEnd = divStart + $(this).width();
        if(divStart < centerLine && divEnd > centerLine){
            //do the thing
        } else {
            //undo the thing
        };
    });
});
```